# R - Create a new column based on number of rows that satisfy requirements in another data frame

Tags: r

I have data frames in the following shape:

```
# firms
firm   year
1      2000
1      2001
1      2002
2      1999
2      2000

# products
product   firm   year   category
100       1      2000   a
101       1      2000   b
102       1      2001   a
103       1      2001   b
104       1      2001   c
105       1      2002   b
106       1      2002   b
107       1      2002   c
108       2      1999   a b
109       2      1999   c
```

I would like to add a column to *firms* that contains a vector of integer values, corresponding to the number of products in *a*, *b*, *c* for a given firm in a given year.

The result should be:

```
# firms
firm   year   vector
1      2000   1 1 0
1      2001   1 1 1
1      2002   0 2 1
2      1999   1 1 1
2      2000   0 0 0
```

Note: The actual data contains 300+ categories.

Data:

```
firms <-
  structure(list(firm = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
                 year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 1999L, 2000L)),
            .Names = c("firm", "year"),
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

products <-
  structure(list(product = 100:109, firm = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
                 year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 1999L, 1999L),
                 category = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "b", "b", "c", "a b", "c")),
            .Names = c("product", "firm", "year", "category"),
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast` after doing a `join`

```
library(data.table)
res <- dcast(setDT(products)[firms, on = c("firm", "year")], firm + year ~category, length)
res[, -ncol(res), with = FALSE]
#   firm year a b c
#1:    1 2000 1 1 0
#2:    1 2001 1 1 1
#3:    1 2002 0 2 1
#4:    2 1999 1 0 1
#5:    2 2000 0 0 0
```

#### Update

Based on the update in the OP's post

```
library(splitstackshape)
res <- dcast(cSplit(products, "category", " ", "long")[firms, 
     on = c("firm", "year")], firm + year ~category, length)
res[, -ncol(res), with = FALSE]
#   firm year a b c
#1:    1 2000 1 1 0
#2:    1 2001 1 1 1
#3:    1 2002 0 2 1
#4:    2 1999 1 1 1
#5:    2 2000 0 0 0
```